# InfoSphere Data Replication 11.4.0 CDC configuration

Tags: db2, cdc, ibm-data-replication

I am trying to configure IIDR CDC from source DB2 (Unix) to target Hadoop. I have installed and created instance on CDC and installed AccessServer, however, i am not able to extract the data from DB2 to non-RDBMS DB. i need help to configure instance, schema and table to extract the DB.

### LIST OF CURRENT INSTANCES

Name      Server Port Database      Schema      Status

---

iidrcdc   10901       CARD          UMT         running

Comment: Chris, Thanks for your help. 
The files are in a csv format right now, however, the Hadoop team asked 
" our standard delimeters which is \x1c, and the files that we typically accept are in a .dsv or .dat format, though we can also accommodate .txt. Are those settings you’re able to configure?
I have tried to create flat file, but it did not ask for Kerberos setting and replication failed.
Please let me know how should i resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

IBM IIDR ( InfoSphere Data Replication)  has different Engines  for various platforms.   They interact with a specific platform/database and require a specific configuration.

You can use the same  product installer from Fix Central to  install the DB2 Engine, and Also the IIDR for DataStage engine  ( which provides options to generate data in Hadoop through WebHDFS API Calls, in addition to flatfiles on local disk for DataStage). 
This will require selecting a separate Engine to install to a SEPARATE  second installation path.   ** you can only have one set of instances/platform  per install path of IIDR, but you can have multiple engines installed on the same host. **

The IIDR community wiki page URL has changed but you can find it here : 
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-data-replication-community-wiki#Hadoop 
along with a slide deck outlining the steps to configure a subscrpition to target Hadoop. 
(https://ibm.ent.box.com/s/w9yxxqi4vs2cfd7v83321hoxgvc7xr9n )

You may need to be aware of  authentication setup for your Hadoop environment.  If  Kerberos authentication is needed,  you may need to identify the principal you are going to use and configure the keys.

With the Target Engine installed and instance created,  you can use the   Management Console  GUI tool  to  configure your  'Subscription' mapping from DB2  to  Hadoop. 
(https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSTRGZ_11.4.0/com.ibm.cdcdoc.mcadminguide.doc/concepts/map_to_hadoop.html )

Chris Schreiber,
IBM IIDR / CDC Team

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are needing is more details on setting up the Subscriptions to  Hadoop using WebHDFS,  but additionally - steps in managing the  Kerberos ticket cache.
(IBM IIDR slide deck on configuring IIDR with  WebHDFS for Haoop:  https://ibm.ent.box.com/s/w9yxxqi4vs2cfd7v83321hoxgvc7xr9n )

Secondly,    you can change the field delimiter in the output flat file, but this requires creating a  Custom User Exit class, which is very minor changes to the  Sample class for the SampleDataFormatForWebHdfs.java

This link would provide more details on compiling the sample user Exits included with the IIDR product install.
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/idr/11.4.0?topic=cdfcreid-compiling-sample-java-class-user-exits-unix-linux

SampleDataFormatForWebHdfs.java   should be used when targeting Hadoop, vs the basic class  SampleDataStageDataFormat.java  as there are some minor differences with quote escaping string values.  Both the Field and row delimiters are specified by variables within the class and can be customized by compiling  your own custom changes to the class and  providing that in the Table mapping details panel for the User Exit class to use.

Chris Schreiber
IBM CDC / IIDR Team